# WPF: cylinder rotation simulation

Tags: wpf, rotation

there's a need to perform simulation of rotation, in particular, a cylinder rotation around longitudinal axis (as shown).

There's a piece of code that performs something remotely similar rotation , however I would like
either improve that code or know another approaches for task solving.
In other words I would like to get a bit better visual results than I am currently having.

[image]

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="120" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Rectangle Width="300" Height="240"  Canvas.Top="0">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush SpreadMethod="Reflect" StartPoint="0,0.0" EndPoint="0,0.25">
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                              From="0.0" To="-120.0"  AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:2"  />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: I think you should use a graphics tool to create the animation e.g, a .gif and then play it in your UI. Or use WPFs 3D engine to create and animate a real 3D shape including texture and lighting ([Microsoft Learn: 3D Graphics Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/3-d-graphics-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#model-and-mesh-primitives)).

Comment: Unless you have texture, I think it'd be quite difficult to see any difference from the side as a plain cylinder rotates.